# What exactly does Backup store?

Tags: backup

I just go by default backup. Therefore, after reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04, I restored the backup, expecting megabytes of LibreOffice Writer files to show up on my desktop. They never appeared after restoring successfully. Did I just wasted my entire work on misunderstanding on what Backup really is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify what directory's you want to backup. Make sure you back up your home directory and etc. This will hopefully cover all your config files and then personal files and documents in your home.

In [BackupYourSystem](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) on help.ubuntu.com you find the Ubuntu backup page. It contains lots of information on backups and the different software packages.

> Did I just wasted my entire work on misunderstanding on what Backup really is?

No you are correct - thats what a backup will do restore files. But in Deja Dup, the default backup suite, you need to make sure you select the directories/partition that you would like to backup. If you didn’t backup the desktop then you will have lost all of those files.

Comment: All I did was involve the directory of the home/'username'. Does that involve desktop directory?

Comment: Also I would like to add that I was just using Backup app. Didn't download Deja Dup or anything else. And I made sure to use the latest update about a week ago before I reinstalled. Does that automatically include the desktop directory?

Comment: The default backup app is deja dup on ubuntu as far as im aware. And yes if you did backup home/*username* then it should have grabbed your desktop directory. So you should be good?

Comment: All right! All files are restored. What I had done during the reinstall was naming the different username and the restore did not restore all. So I reinstall second time to use the same username. Thanks for your help. Just wanted to be clear if I understood what Backup is. It works. Ubuntu is the best OS of all.

Comment: No bother. Mark as solved if your all good! :)

Comment: Hmm... How do I flag it as solved?